# How to approach this question (multivariable calculus/limits)?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The thing is I don't want any direct answer I just need a tip of a trick that I can apply to get the magic. I am not really interested in the answer, so please don't write the answer for the question but rather how to approach and think about the question.

I'm given the following

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,-2)}\frac{\ln(x^4-y^4+1)}{x^2-y^2}.  $$

I obviously have tried to approach it from the $x$ axis by setting $y=0$ and so from the $y$ axis by setting $x =0$ but it didn't help out because when you set $x=0$ you end up with an undefined answer in $\mathbb R$. Mathematica tho says that the limit converges to $8$
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If a is small then $ln(1+a)=a-\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}+...$ so you can do away with the ln. Try going from there.

Comment: Look up the Taylor series of ln(1+x) and keep $0\le x^4-y^4 < 1$ e.g. see http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf

Comment: Substituting $z=x^2-y^2$ and $w=x^2+y^2$ might be helpful, but I'm not certain whether the details all work.

Comment: Knowing that $\lim\limits_{t\to0} \frac{\ln(1+t)}t=1$ might simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote you only want a hint: Try to use that
$\lim\limits_{t\to0} \frac{\ln(1+t)}t=1$ might simplify things a bit.

More details are hidden below:

> Using the above you should get $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,-2)}\frac{\ln(x^4-y^4+1)}{x^2-y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (2,-2)} \frac{x^4-y^4}{x^2-y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (2,-2)} (x^2+y^2).$$

---

BTW you wrote in your post that you get undefined result if you set $x=0$. By undefined answer you mean that you get limit in indeterminate form? WA returns 8 for that limit:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+y-%3E2+ln%2817-y%5E4%29%2F%284-y%5E2%29 (But I agree that computation of this limit is of similar difficulty as the original limit in your post.)